# Change Vue component's data value in Storybook

Tags: vue.js, storybook

I've got a modal component that has 2 states based on the value of the `isSent` boolean (false by default).

```js
<template>
  <SimpleModal>
    <div v-if="!isSent">
       ...
    </div>

    <div v-else>
       ...
    </div>
  </SimpleModal>
<template>
```

Therefore I'd like to create 2 stories, one for each state.
My problem is that I can't seem to change the value of `isSent` like so:

```js
storiesOf('common.Modals.ShareBookingModal', module)
  .add('Normal', withReadme(ShareBookingModalReadme, () => ({
    components : { ShareBookingModal },
    template   : `
      <div class="sb-container">
        <ShareBookingModal />
      </div>
    `
  }))).add('Success', withReadme(ShareBookingModalReadme, () => ({
    components : { ShareBookingModal },
    template   : `
    <div class="sb-container">
      <ShareBookingModal />
    </div>
  `,

    data() {
      return {
        isSent : true // not doing its job
      };
    }
})));
```

In both stories, the first `div` is displayed.

How may I modify the component's state directly?

Comment: I know it's an old question, but did you find a solution?